# Implement document repository for web application

Tags: java, repository, webdav

Im currently looking to implement a document repository for a web application (i.e. a user opens a document and saves it directly on a server). I've done some research and found WebDAV that has support for this (www.webdav.org).
However, WebDAV seems to lack firefoxsupport unless you download and use a extention. I'm looking for a way to accomplish this without the need for a 3rd party extention

Questions:

```
How can this be accomplished with webDAV without a 3rd party extention?
Is there another lib/way to accomplish this?
```

Answer (score 0):

John, thats right you can launch documents in the appropriate editor (eg Word, Excel) directly from IE but to do the same in FF or Chrome requires some sort of extension.

Note that with webdav your users can browse for documents on the server as if they are on a normal drive, and open them using normal tools such as windows explorer or the file open dialog.

I routinely assist customers implementing this with my webdav server library product - http://milton.io

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Framework you can enable support for multipart upload and then just use the standard java form upload functionality from any web browser to upload the document to your web server.

Comment: multipart form upload does not allow users to open a file and 'save directly on the server', as the OP asked.

Comment: Yes it does. What is an upload to a website if not a save to the server? It also is supported on every single browser without the need for any plugins - which was an important point of the requirements and it is pretty much the only way to meet that requirement.

Comment: The OP specifically said "save directly on the server" that means saving to the server from the application in which the document was edited, such as Word or Excel.

Web apps which implement webdav support this, because you can open your word or excel document directly from the server and when you click save in word or excel the document is saved to the server.